# How to save Google Chrome Developer Tools Javascript debugging Session including breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I've searched for this information and failed to find the answer so hopefully someone here knows if it can be done or not.
- When debugging javascript I often set a number of breakpoints.
- Dev Tools remembers them unless I clear the breakpoints to debug other pages.
- When this happens and I return to continue debugging the original page I have to manually re-enter all the breakpoints.

Is there any way to save a Google Chrome Developer Tools session complete with all the breakpoints to a file so you can resume later without having to manually renter the breakpoints?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Jared Wyles](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/x_QZEBydRhA) seems to have hacked together something like this back in 2013. However, he seems to have since gone silent?

Comment: Looking at the video he linked in the post it looks like what I want but I see that he shared how to do it... or did I miss it?
 Anybody else have a suggestion?